# How to post array with nodejs http request

Tags: php, node.js, arrays, request, http-post

The PHP API request array as input. Based on the example it is also need to be convert by http_build_query.

```
$curl_parameters['order_ids'] = array(123,456,789);

$curl_options = array(
    ...
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($curl_parameters),
    ...
  );
```

The first part of the script is always like it is below.

```
  const order_ids = { "order_ids": [123,456,789] }   //This is the right format. Created by CBroe. **typeof => object**

const order = httpBuildQuery(order_ids)  // typeof => string

const options = {
    mehod: 'POST',                                             
    auth: username + ":" + password,
    body: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    json: true,
  };
```

The https request part looks like this. I copied both of the used version of req.write with the received error codes but of course one time I use one type of it.

```
const req = http.request(url, options, (res) => {                   
    
    res.on('data', (d) => {                                 
        process.stdout.write(d);
      });                                           

  req.write(order);   //error=> implode(): Invalid arguments passed.{"result":"success","event":"getawb","msg":[]}
//typeof req.write(order) => boolean


  req.end();

};
```

The [httpBuildQuery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-build-query) is an npm package.

I also checked what can be the PHP buildquery function and the result is the same like in my code:
0=123&1=456&2=789.

So it's looks like everything is according to the API requirements but some reason the script can not send the right array.

The main question is, how to send array with nodejs?

**Update:**

The following format works with PHP: "order_ids%5B0%5D=123&order_ids%5B1%5D=456&order_ids%5B2%5D=789"

I modified the code above based on it. The httpbuildquery npm package create a same format, but some reason the response message still the "Invalid arguments passed".

So I think the main issue is how the message send to server. How should I send the array message to server?

Comment: You can not pass an array with numeric keys to `httpBuildQuery`, it needs to be an object, which it can also determine the parameter _name_ to use from. You should use an object here that has `order_ids` as a key, and the value below that the array with your IDs.

Comment: Thanks CBroe but I'm not sure I understand. So firs of all I should use obcejt => const order_ids=[123,456,789]. And the format also need to be defined in the options? Like this?  => body:{'order_ids': order_ids}.  Or how to proceed?

Comment: I am talking about something like `{ "order_ids": [1, 2, 3] }`

Comment: I tried it but do not work. Still get a same error message.  I really stuck at this point. I can not send array to API server .

Comment: What is the exact format that you are _supposed_ to send? _“I also checked what can be the PHP buildqeury function and the result is the same like in my code: 0=123&1=456&2=789.”_ - not sure what you are referring to here. `http_build_query` used with the `$curl_parameters` array as you have shown above, should result in `order_ids%5B0%5D=123&order_ids%5B1%5D=456&order_ids%5B2%5D=789`.

Comment: Yes exactly what you wrote.  This is the format which is working in PHP => order_ids%5B0%5D=123&order_ids%5B1%5D=456&order_ids%5B2%5D=789. Bascially the http_build_query npm package create a same. But some reason when I send it via node request (req.write) I got invalid argument message. So I think the way how I send this data is not ok.

Comment: Well that’s probably because you are still trying to send `order_ids`, instead of the actual result of the `httpBuildQuery` call.

Comment: I save it to new variable but not works. var orders= httpBuildQuery(order_ids ) and then I put it to the function. req.write(orders);. And still come back the invalid argument. Is it any other way how to send information to server?

Comment: Can you check what `typeof` returns for `orders`? If you call `req.write` with the exact same content, provided as a static text literal, does that work?

Comment: `mehod: 'POST'` – can’t tell if that type is part of your actual code.

Comment: `body: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', }`  what is that supposed to be? Apart from the fact that the format your are trying to send is _not_ JSON, why are you trying to stick _headers_ into the _body_?

Comment: I added the types of the values. There is object, string and boolean. I also deleted json part of the option.  Is it possible to contact you with other way where can I share my screen? I'm new here so I can not chat to you but I would really appreciate it.